# Tag wiki edit aproval

Tags: discussion

I was wondering, if you need to approve a tag wiki and you notice that there is a spelling mistake or a grammar error. What do you do?

Reject or Approve (when approved just immediately correct the error)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Approve and edit. Someone else put in the hard work to get the wiki there, let them have the credit and rep.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, just wanted to make sure it was the right thing ^^

Answer (score 1):

Generally the only time I reject a Tag Wiki is when it's an obvious copy-paste with obvious problems that the author should have corrected (i.e. "You wanted rep so you did a quick, lazy, ***BAD*** copy-paste from Wikipedia & didn't provide attribution or fix up formatting").
Usually my rejection message calls out the most egregious badness and invites the author to submit a revised version that meets our (relatively low) standards for tag wikis.